# Wordpress Customizer (functions.php) - site crashes (500)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

**Hello Fellow Code-Wrestlers!**
*(I think providing only this snippet from the functions.php should be enough for this case)*

I was wondering if you could tell me that I wronte something wrong in here? I can't figure it out.

So I am not yet replacing any values, I just want the "box" to show up in the theme customizer. Following this guide, I think it should work:
[THE_LINK](http://ottopress.com/2012/how-to-leverage-the-theme-customizer-in-your-own-themes/)

Thank you so much in advance!

```
$wp_customize->add_section( 'calmarstudio_color_scheme', array(
    'title'          => __( 'Color Scheme', 'calmarstudio' ),
    'priority'       => 35,
) );

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'calmarstudio_theme_options[color_scheme]', array(
    'default'        => 'some-default-value',
    'type'           => 'option',
    'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
) );

$wp_customize->add_control( 'calmarstudio_color_scheme', array(
    'label'      => __( 'Color Scheme', 'calmarstudio' ),
    'section'    => 'calmarstudio_color_scheme',
    'settings'   => 'calmarstudio_theme_options[color_scheme]',
    'type'       => 'radio',
    'choices'    => array(
        'value1' => 'Choice 1',
        'value2' => 'Choice 2',
        'value3' => 'Choice 3',
        ),
) );
```

Comment: Well, what does your http servers error log file say what the issue is?

Comment: @arkascha i actually get this:

Comment: Please do not add additional information in comments. There is an `edit` link below your question. _Use it_.

Comment: @arkascha i actually get this:
'
Notice: Undefined variable: wp_customize in /var/www/wp_templating/wp-content/themes/calmar_studio/functions.php on line 81

Fatal error: Call to a member function add_section() on null in /var/www/wp_templating/wp-content/themes/calmar_studio/functions.php on line 81'

I get that I must define what wp_customize is beforehand. Now I guess i can give it $wp_customize = null; or something... that should work (?).

The second error isn't clear to me. let me check what happens when I give it a variable.

Comment: Looks like you have to read into the documentation of that function a bit deeper. The error simply says that you are trying to call an object method on something that is not an object. Obviously that cannot work. So the question is: _if_ wordpress prepares some object to be used in that function, then what is it's name?

Comment: @arkascha thanks for reminding me of the log. I am sometimes too lazy to look at it. which gives me headaches ^^

Comment: You _cannot_ program php in a web based environment without monitoring the http servers error log file. That is like flying blind inside a narrow cave.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a solution:
[STACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372934/wordpress-call-to-a-member-function-add-section-on-a-non-object-in-functions-p)

I was wrong about needing to define the wp_customize like this: **wp_customize = null;**. Simply adding the it in the function function **color_customize($wp_customize) { THECODE }** solved it. works like a charm.

Comment: Obviously `$wp_customize = null` does not make any sense. `null` is _not_ an object.

Comment: @arkascha I am now having another issue. I seem to have only setup the barebone. But it does not save the selected anywhere.

Comment: @arkascha I am now having another issue. I seem to have only setup the barebone. But it does not save the selected anywhere. 
here another stack overflow of mine ;) --> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41284542/wordpress-save-an-option-form-customizer)LINK[link]